# Cipher functions : WRONG FINAL BLOCK LENGTH Android Studio

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

There are a lot of threads on stack overflow with this topic, and always the same solutions, but these doesn't work for me. I am looking for a way to decrypt the value `byte[]` encrypted and return `byte[]` decodedBytes.

With the method AESCrypt. I use `compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'`

```
private void testAES() {
    try {

       final byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode("R3JhbmRlIFZpY3RvaXJlICE=", Base64.NO_WRAP);

       byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode("L/91ZYrliXvmhYt9FKEkkDDni+PzcnOuV9cikm188+4=", Base64.NO_WRAP);
       final byte[] ivBytes = Base64.decode("gqjFHI+YQiP7XYEfcIEJHw==".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

       final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

       byte[] decodedBytes = AESCrypt.decrypt(keySpec, ivBytes, encrypted);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

With the value Cipher, i use it like that.

```
private static byte[] testCipher() {

    try {

        final byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode("R3JhbmRlIFZpY3RvaXJlICE=", Base64.NO_WRAP);

        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode("L/91ZYrliXvmhYt9FKEkkDDni+PzcnOuV9cikm188+4=", Base64.NO_WRAP);
        byte[] ivBytes = Base64.decode("gqjFHI+YQiP7XYEfcIEJHw==".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        final IvParameterSpec ivSpecForData = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        SecretKeySpec decodedKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decodedKeySpec, ivSpecForData);

        byte[] decodedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encrypted); // I have the error here //

        return decodedBytes;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Whatever i do, i allways have the same error :

`error:1e06b07b:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH`

I try to put in Cipher.getInstance (AES/CBC/NoPadding, AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding) but nothing change.
Do you have any idea to help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A padding error can mean any number of things: wrong key, wrong encoding, incomplete/overfull ciphertext. You should show the encryption code and give the example values that you've used. Otherwise, it would be plain guessing what might be wrong with this code (or the encryption code). In short, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi did you find an answer? I'm stuck with the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"R3JhbmRlIFZpY3RvaXJlICE="` decoded to 17 hex bytes `4772616E646520566963746F6972652021` which is the ASCII text: "Grande Victoire !".

17 bytes is not a valid size for AES which is a block cipher that requires encrypted data to be a multiple of the block size of 16-bytes.

There is no encryption just Base64 encoding.

Comment: Thank's. I really thought that the AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding could hash the bytes and could fill the last block directly. I have basically the same code in IOS but it works and i don't know why.
If you know the difference between those two tell me if you can , cause i m still stuck in my decryption code.

Comment: @zaph, can you please point out the solution for this. I am getting encrypted strings from our server and I am able to decrypt most of it, but some others are throwing this error.